# Within form the value of <input type="button"> not submitting

Tags: php, forms, model-view-controller

I have searched for this topic but no one shows the same problem as I do.

I have a button with a certain value. When submitting the form I want the value to be sent to a controller so to be save in a database. All other information sent is accurate but independently of the button's value what is saved is a 0.

Why is that? Thanks in advance!

```
<div class="container">
    <?php $row = $query->row(); ?>
        <div class="current"> <?php echo $row->text;?> </div>
            <form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url();?>questionnaire/process">         

               <div class="form-group">
                    <label> Número Pergunta </label> 
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="question" value=" <?php echo $row->text;?>">
               </div>

                <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="...">
                    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                        <input type="button" name = "choice" value= "1" class="btn btn-default">
                    </div>

                    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                        <input  type="button" name = "choice" value= "2" class="btn btn-default">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <input type="submit" value="Próxima" />
            </form>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see the note from the below link

> **"Note: In a form, the button and its value is only submitted if the button itself was used to submit the form."**

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_value.asp

I would recommend changing your inputs to something like a radio button list and styling it as a button if you require buttons specifically

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Buttons only use to trigger actions, not submit with form data.

Check this: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.5

**Solutions:**
You can use Radio OR Dropdowns to pick submit your choice values

**Radio:**

```
<input  type="radio" name = "choice" value= "1" class="btn btn-default">
<input  type="radio" name = "choice" value= "2" class="btn btn-default">
```

**Dropdown:**

```
<SELECT name = "choice">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
</SELECT>
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Fox909a, only the clicked submit button sends values.

If javascript is an exceptable addition, you can save the value in a hidden field:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="...">
    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <input onclick="this.form.choice.value=this.value;" type="button" value= "1" class="btn btn-default">
     </div>

     <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <input onclick="this.form.choice.value=this.value;" type="button"  value= "2" class="btn btn-default">
      </div>
 </div>
 <input type="hidden" name="choice" id="choice"/>
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/mLxs9j27/ (choice field is not hidden in example, so you can see it working)